Ruby on Rails 7 bootstrap 5 drop down navbar doesn't work
I'm trying to run some example rails app with bootstrap 5. I created dropdown menu but the navbar not dropping down. I tried all tutorials and nothing works. There is my configuration:
Rails 7.1.3.2

yarn -v
1.22.19

node --version
v20.12.1

The Gemfile
gem "rails", "~> 7.1.3"

gem "sprockets-rails"

gem "pg", "~> 1.1"

gem "puma", ">= 5.0"

gem "jsbundling-rails"

gem "turbo-rails"

gem "stimulus-rails"

gem "cssbundling-rails"

gem "jbuilder"

gem "jquery-ui-rails"
gem "jquery-rails"
gem "tzinfo-data", platforms: %i[ windows jruby ]

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem "bootsnap", require: false

# Use Active Storage variants [https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#transforming-images]
# gem "image_processing", "~> 1.2"

group :development, :test do
  # See https://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#debugging-with-the-debug-gem
  gem "debug", platforms: %i[ mri windows ]
end

group :development do
  # Use console on exceptions pages [https://github.com/rails/web-console]
  gem "web-console"
group :test do
  # Use system testing [https://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#system-testing]
  gem "capybara"
  gem "selenium-webdriver"
end

File app/javascript/application.js
// Entry point for the build script in your package.json
import "@hotwired/turbo-rails"
import "./controllers"
import * as bootstrap from "bootstrap"

File app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Knfapp</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= csp_meta_tag %>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", "data-turbo-track": "reload" %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbo-track": "reload", type: "module", defer: true %>
  </head>

  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            Dropdown link
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
    <%= yield %>
    <footer><p>little</p></footer>
  </body>
</html>

Project run with command:
rails new abcapp -d postgresql -j esbuild --css bootstrap

I'm sitting on it a few hours but nothing works. I will be grateful for any suggestion.

It looks like I needed just run
yarn build

and
rails assets:precompile

to make that work.

No you don't need to do this in development.  When you run your rails 7 app, when using esbuild, you use bin/dev.  This should compile your javascript and css and run your rails server.
